# Explanation of matrix iteration optimization

Tags: c, loops, optimization, matrix, iteration

I'm studying for my final exam and I'm going over some optimization techniques. For some reason, there's not a lot of information on this particular example and I don't understand it, so maybe I can get some help.

In the Powerpoint slides, there is this example of strength reduction.

```
c1 = f();
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  c2 = c1 + g(i);
  int ri = n * i;
  for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    a[ ri + j ] = c2 + h(j);
}
```

can be transformed into

```
c1 = f();
*p = a;
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
  c2 = c1 + g(i);
  for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    *p++ = c2 + h(j);
}
```

How is this the same code? I don't understand because incrementing a pointer just moves it up one element and the original moves up a lot more than 1 for every i value. Is there some error or am I missing something?

Comment: because incrementing `*p` is equivalent to indexing `a[ri + j]`

Comment: The idea is that the pointer will keep on going, so after one j loop it will point to a[n], after two a[2*n] etc. That is why it needs no ri in it.

Comment: To be identical, you have to put `p = a;` instead of `*p = a;` or you will run into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ignore all of the calculations, and just look at the loop counters…

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    printf("%d\n", n * i + j);
}
```

You'll see that `ri + j`, which is `n * i + j`, counts up from 0 (inclusive) to n<sup>2</sup> (exclusive).  Therefore, `a[ri + j]` is just walking along the array one element at a time.  You can do the same walk with `p++`.

Answer (score 2):

The code goes through an array of n*n elements. In the first one it is indexed like by row and column, which are calculated separately and then added together. But since the data is in one array without gaps, there is no need to calculate the indexes this way for sequential access.

If you think about the indexer in the first: `i*n + j`, it means that after i goes up by one, the indexer goes up by n. In the second one the pointer moves forward one position after every element, so when the `j` loop goes from 0 to n-1, `i` turns into 1 and the pointer `p` has moved n elements forward. So it points to `a[1*n+0]`, which is equivalent to `i*n+j` at this position. And this is continued until the end.